DataDog delay notification until business hours
I have a Cron job that runs once per day at 3am, and have set up a DataDog monitor to alert if the endpoint it calls fails.  It's a high enough priority alert that the on-call person should get paged (especially if it happens over the weekend), but it's not so urgent that they need to be paged at 3:00 in the morning.
Is it possible in DataDog to delay the alert until later in the morning (9:00am for example)?

There are no straightforward options available to send the notification at a different time. But, you can set the "Evaluation delay" to 6 hours(in seconds) which will move the monitor to alert state at 9 AM if the cron job fails at 3 am.
https://docs.datadoghq.com/monitors/configuration/?tab=thresholdalert#evaluation-delay

You can use a downtime on the monitor to prevent notifications overnight. I believe you can then configure the downtime expiration settings to trigger a notification if the monitor is still in an alert state when the downtime ends.
